# GSA: Get Synonym word in frontend

Tags: google-search-appliance

When I entered hometowm in google search I get
**Showing results for hometown
Search instead for hometowm**

I want this feature in my custom front end. How to show this

Answer (score 0):

One way to do is Search>Front Ends>Related Queries

Add Search Term as **hometowm** and Related Query as **hometown**

Answer (score 0):

create a .txt synonyms file
**{hometown , hometown Search}** and apply **utf-8** encoding on it.

now upload this file in **search >> search features >> Query setting >> Query expansion file >> synonyms**.

enable **query expansion policy = full** for your frontend from **Search >> frontend >> filter** tab.

now add **entqr=3** in query request of your custom frontend for retrieving synonyms.